# How to get SQL query HAVING count display BOTH records with the same value where INNER JOIN exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is the current query:

```
SELECT schedule.routenr, stops.stopname, schedule.scheduletime FROM schedule 
INNER JOIN stops ON
schedule.id_stop=stops.id_stop
INNER JOIN tram ON
schedule.id_tram=tram.id_tram
WHERE tram.id_direction = '5' AND  stops.stopname = 'Stourton' AND 
schedule.scheduletime >= ('10:50:00') 
OR tram.id_direction = '5' AND stops.stopname = 'CitySquare'

ORDER BY schedule.routenr ASC, schedule.scheduletime ASC;
```

These are the results displayed:

```
route_nr    stopname      scheduletime

1           CitySquare    09:57:00
2           Stourton      11:50:00
2           CitySquare    11:57:00  
3           Stourton      12:50:00 
3           CitySquare    12:57:00
```

Query Results with adding HAVING COUNT(schedule.routenr) > 1

```
route_nr    stopname      scheduletime
2           Stourton      11:50:00
```

I want to be able to display both records that have the duplicate count in route_nr so that stopname = Stourton and stopname = CitySquare are both displayed. This is what it should display.

```
route_nr    stopname      scheduletime

2           Stourton      11:50:00
2           CitySquare    11:57:00  
3           Stourton      12:50:00 
3           CitySquare    12:57:00
```

This is the list of Tables with data:

```
tram                                   stops
id_tram  id_direction                  id_stop  stopname
1        1                             1        GrimesDyke
2        1                             2        SeacroftRingRoad 
3        1                             3        WykeBeck
4        1                             4        FfordeGrene
5        2                             5        St.James'sHospital
6        2                             6        QuarryHill
7        2                             7        Eastgate
8        2                             8        CitySquare
9        2                             9        Bodington
10       2                             10       HeadingleyCentre
11       3                             11       HydeParkCorner
12       3                             12       UniversityofLeeds
13       3                             13       Civic
14       4                             14       Riverside
15       5                             15       ClarenceDock
                                       16       StJoseph's
                                       17       ChurchStreet
                                       18       Stourton
                                       19       BalmRoad
                                       20       BelleIsleNorth
                                       21       BelleIsleCentral
                                       22       BelleIsleSouth
                                       23       MiddletonDistrictCentre
                                       24       MiddletonCircus
                                       25       Tingley

schedule
id_schedule   id_tram   id_stop  routenr  scheduletime
1             15        18       1        09:50:00
2             15        18       2        11:50:00
3             15        18       3        12:50:00
4             15        8        1        09:57:00
5             15        8        2        11:57:00
6             15        8        3        12:57:00
7             15        8        1        09:42:00
8             14        18       1        09:49:00
9             14        8        2        11:42:00
10            14        18       2        11:49:00
```

Comment: FuzzyTree and Gordon Linoff at your service, you're in good hands! Try adding sample data, so the solutions can be tested.

Comment: Im glad to hear, im really struggling trying to figure this out. What sort of sample data should i add ? all tables used ?

Comment: Yes that would be helpful and some records to have as dummy data. You could use sqlfiddle too for better collaboration (sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: I will try to upload all of that to sqlfiddle

Comment: This is the fiddle:   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d95571

Comment: Thank you for the help, everyone who tried to figure this out :) I'm super grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
select tmp.routenr, maintable.stopname, maintable.scheduletime 
from(
    SELECT sc.routenr, st.stopname, sc.scheduletime 
    FROM schedule sc
    INNER JOIN stops st
        ON sc.id_stop = st.id_stop
    INNER JOIN tram tr
        ON sc.id_tram = tr.id_tram
    WHERE tr.id_direction = '5' AND  st.stopname = 'Stourton' AND 
        sc.scheduletime >= ('10:50:00') 
        OR tr.id_direction = '5' AND st.stopname = 'CitySquare'
     ) maintable
inner join ( 
    SELECT sc1.routenr, count(*) as routenr_count
    FROM schedule sc1
    INNER JOIN stops st1
        ON sc1.id_stop = st1.id_stop
    INNER JOIN tram 
        ON sc1.id_tram = tr1.id_tram
    WHERE tr1.id_direction = '5' AND  st1.stopname = 'Stourton' AND 
        sc1.scheduletime >= ('10:50:00') 
        OR tr1.id_direction = '5' AND st1.stopname = 'CitySquare'
    group by sc1.routenr
    ) tmp
on tmp.routenr = maintable.routenr
where tmp.routenr_count > 1
ORDER BY maintable.routenr ASC, maintable.scheduletime ASC;
```

I wonder about `or` clause, could you confirm it is right? Because i think it should be something like

```
where (tram.id_direction = '5' AND  stops.stopname = 'Stourton' AND 
        schedule.scheduletime >= ('10:50:00') 
      )
      OR 
      (tram.id_direction = '5' AND stops.stopname = 'CitySquare'
      )
```

Editted: Changed so it work as your sample data. Another solution should be 2nd solution `route_nr in (...)` from `Gordon Linoff` (correct your intention of `OR` in his query first)

Comment: the first long query does not work, empty results once again :/

Comment: I did notice the missing ) when I first ran the query, but the results did still not display.

Comment: @camnesia Can you run and say how many rows you get if you only run the subquery in `tmp` ?

Comment: I can try but im not sure what exactly you are asking me to run :D

Comment: @camnesia Editted my answer according to your sample data. You could check it now.

Comment: whoooooop :D it finally works. Thank you so much !! You are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it will be good enough to put the records for each `route_nr` on a single row.  If so:

```
SELECT s.routenr, GROUP_CONCAT(st.stopname ORDER BY s.scheduletime) as stopnames,
       GROUP_CONCAT(s.scheduletime ORDER BY s.scheduletime) as schedules
FROM schedule s INNER JOIN
     stops st
     ON s.id_stop = st.id_stop INNER JOIN
     tram t
     ON s.id_tram = t.id_tram
WHERE (t.id_direction = '5' AND  st.stopname = 'Stourton' AND 
s.scheduletime >= '10:50:00') OR
      (t.id_direction = '5' AND st.stopname = 'CitySquare')
GROUP BY s.routenr
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

If you actually want the original rows, then you need a more complicated query that is cumbersome in MySQL (but not in other databases).  One way is to repeat the logic of the outer query:

```
SELECT s.routenr, st.stopname, s.scheduletime
FROM schedule s INNER JOIN
     stops st
     ON s.id_stop = st.id_stop INNER JOIN
     tram t
     ON s.id_tram = t.id_tram
WHERE ((t.id_direction = '5' AND  st.stopname = 'Stourton' AND 
s.scheduletime >= '10:50:00') OR
       (t.id_direction = '5' AND st.stopname = 'CitySquare')
      ) AND
      s.routenr IN (SELECT s.routenr
                    FROM schedule s INNER JOIN
                         stops st
                         ON s.id_stop = st.id_stop INNER JOIN
                         tram t
                         ON s.id_tram = t.id_tram
                    WHERE (t.id_direction = '5' AND  st.stopname = 'Stourton' AND s.scheduletime >= '10:50:00') OR
                          (t.id_direction = '5' AND st.stopname = 'CitySquare')
                    GROUP BY s.routenr
                    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                  );
```

Comment: That sadly displayed no results at all.

Comment: It is still returning with no results at all. Im not sure why.

Comment: @camnesia . . . Does the first query return results?  It is essentially your query with the `group by` and `group_concat()`.

Comment: It sadly does not, this is the database to test it on: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d95571

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT schedule.routenr, stops.stopname, schedule.scheduletime FROM schedule 
INNER JOIN stops ON
schedule.id_stop=stops.id_stop
INNER JOIN tram ON
schedule.id_tram=tram.id_tram
WHERE tram.id_direction = '5' AND  stops.stopname = 'Stourton' AND 
schedule.scheduletime >= ('10:50:00') OR tram.id_direction = '5' AND 
stops.stopname = 'CitySquare' AND schedule.routenr 
in (SELECT s.routenr FROM schedule s
INNER JOIN stops ON
schedule.id_stop=stops.id_stop
INNER JOIN tram ON
schedule.id_tram=tram.id_tram
WHERE tram.id_direction = '5' AND  stops.stopname = 'Stourton' AND 
schedule.scheduletime >= ('10:50:00') 
OR tram.id_direction = '5' AND stops.stopname = 'CitySquare'
GROUP BY s.routenr
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

Comment: Sadly the same problem as with the previous answer, no records are displayed when running this query

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem is to simulate `row_number` using variables to enumerate the rows in each `route_nr` group by `schedule_time` in both ascending and descending order. All rows where one of the row numbers is greater than 1 are part of a `route_nr` group with more than 1 row:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * ,
        @prevc2 := IF(@prev2 = routenr, @prevc2+1, 1) rn2,
        @prev2 := routenr
    FROM (
        SELECT schedule.routenr, stops.stopname, schedule.scheduletime,
            @prevc1 := IF(@prev1 = schedule.routenr, @prevc1+1, 1) rn1,
            @prev1 := schedule.routenr
        FROM schedule 
        INNER JOIN stops ON
        schedule.id_stop=stops.id_stop
        INNER JOIN tram ON
        schedule.id_tram=tram.id_tram
        WHERE tram.id_direction = '5' AND  stops.stopname = 'Stourton' AND 
        schedule.scheduletime >= ('10:50:00') 
        OR tram.id_direction = '5' AND stops.stopname = 'CitySquare'
        ORDER BY schedule.routenr ASC, schedule.scheduletime ASC
    ) t 
    ORDER BY routenr ASC, scheduletime DESC
) t WHERE rn1 > 1 OR rn2 > 1
```